# Regular expression match for specific string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a below string to compare in PHP.and i made one regular expression for match the string.But it only match exactly same string so can some one help to get me regular expression to match below conditional string.

I have used below expression.

```
[poBox]\s\d{3}
```

below is my conditional string to match

```
POBox 123, POBox 1234, P.O.Box 123, P.O.Box 1234, P O Box 123, P O Box 1234, P.O. Box 123, P.O. Box 1234
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Conditional string is my expected output.if user input any one of them it should match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[poBox]` means any one character between `p`, `o`, `B` or `x`. And `\d{3}` will not match the full extent of `1234`.

```
P\.?\s?O\.?\s?Box\s\d+
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xY7dT3/1).

Comment: Also, they can type "box" with a small "b".

Comment: @SergeyVidusov: That was not in any of your examples, and demonstrates how important it is to have exhaustive good and bad examples. As to your follow-up, I already taught you how to match one of several characters; you can just apply that: replace `B` with `[Bb]`. EDIT: sorry OP, didn't notice it wasn't you.

Comment: You should escape the dots, `p\.? ?o\.? box \d+` with `i` flag.

Comment: @Tushar: Eh derp on dots, thanks. `i` flag would also match `"BoX"`.

Comment: @Tushar: Won't match `P. O. Box`, where you need dots *and* spaces (EDIT: which I just realised now that OP doesn't list, so maybe you have a point). And `[.\s]*` would match `"P .O .Box"`, `"P....O....Box"` and other undesirables.

Comment: In the formats included, I don't see where both `.` and space is used in between `P` and `O`.

Comment: @Tushar: Yup, edited my comment. Again, lack of exhaustive positive and negative examples...